# text clicked on first and second activity, should be visible to third

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am trying to find best way to  show textview we have clicked on first and second activity, in third one.

Like i have three activities AccountFrom, AccountTo and transferDetails.
   I want to know that on what accounttype user has clicked so that i can show in third activity.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Save the text from TextView on `sharedPreferences` when it is clicked. Then read it on your third activity.

Call this on your first activity where the user chooses the account type.

```
void saveText(String stringFromTextView)
{
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("account", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("account_type", stringFromTextView);
    editor.commit();

}
```

And on your third activity, call this on onCreate() to get the account type.

```
String getAccountType()
{
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("account", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String accountType = sharedpreferences.getString("account_type", null);
    return accountType;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
1. on AccountFrom Activity
Intent intent = new Intent(AccountFrom.this, AccountTo.class);
**intent.putExtra("accounttype","accountTypeVariable");**
startActivity(intent);

2. Receive intent on AccountTo Activity
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent != null)
{
   String accountTypeValue = intent.getStringExtra("accounttype")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a view model.

You create the view model in the first Activity and then it is accessible in all activities that you open from it.

Here is simple workflow:

1. Create view model class that extends ViewModel and has the values you need to keep around

   ```
   public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
       private String value1 = "";
       private boolean isValue2 = false;
       // ...
   }
   ```
2. In the first activity create your view model class member

   ```
   private MyViewModel viewModel;
   ```
3. In the OnCreate you can get the view model like this:

   ```
   viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
   ```
4. You can do it also in the activities that are launched from this activity - they will share the same view model object. You can set the values in the activities and access them in other activities from the same 'launch-chain'.

When the initial activity (your first one) gets destroyed then the view model also does.

PS. using view model is also good when you need to handle screen orientation changes.